# Thrown exception does not get catched in `on` clause (type seems to be wrong)

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, try-catch

I have an asynchronous method with a try catch block and it calls another async method that throws. My problem is that the thrown exception is not catched in the catch block.

```
Future savePlayer(Player player) async {
  try {
    var store = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await store.setString(_playerId, jsonEncode(player.toJson()));   // exception in player.toJson() "NoSuchMethod"
  } on Exception catch (err) {
    throw LocalStorageException(                                     // no catch here
        message: TextConstants.exception.localStorageSaveException,
        hint: TextConstants.exception.localStorageSaveExceptionHint,
        originalExceptionText: err.toString());
  } catch (err) {
    throw LocalStorageException(                                     // catch here, but why?
        message: TextConstants.exception.localStorageSaveException,
        hint: TextConstants.exception.localStorageSaveExceptionHint,
        originalExceptionText: err.toString());
  }
}
```

If I remove `on Exception` and just use the `catch`, then it works. This would be a valid workaround for me. But as I am using the Effective Dart coding rules I get a warning when omitting the on clause.

https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_catches_without_on_clauses.html

What is the correct way to catch ANY exception in a catch block with an `on` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on Exception` catches objects of type `Exception`.

What is being thrown is a [`NoSuchMethodError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.2/dart-core/NoSuchMethodError-class.html), which is an [`Error`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/Error-class.html). `Error`s are not `Exception`s (nor vice-versa).

Dart distinguishes between *runtime* errors and *logical* errors (programmer errors).  Runtime errors should derive from `Exception`; logical errors should derive from `Error`.

[Effective Dart discourages catching `Error`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-explicitly-catch-error-or-types-that-implement-it).  They usually represent a programming mistake that could have and should have been avoided (e.g. calling a non-existent function).